# How to read in a specific number with sscanf from lines which are similar?

Tags: c, scanf

I'm trying to read in a specific number from a file with the `sscanf()`function in the `C` standard library. My example data comes from `/proc/stat` on a system running a `Linux Kernel`. Here is how it looks:

```
cpu  90158 11772 50095 6885572 36975 0 207 0 0 0
cpu0 22942 2975 12847 1720241 9655 0 58 0 0 0
cpu1 23879 2979 12080 1717405 12483 0 45 0 0 0
cpu2 21510 3105 12864 1722238 7790 0 57 0 0 0
cpu3 21824 2712 12301 1725687 7044 0 45 0 0 0
.
.
.
intr 2108705 19 28724 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 90871 0 0 204911 0 0 0 143 0 0 0 0 35 0     0 0 0 2362 0 101810 25 388 0 404786 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
ctxt 11136028
btime 1423918994
processes 155184
procs_running 2
procs_blocked 1
softirq 2109698 8 644880 168 19330 95660 0 24557 551780 3897 769418
```

I try to print all lines after the `if`-statement except those lines containing `cpu` directly followed (without a whitespace) by a number. That is the first line `cpu` should be printed with all the others but e.g. not the second line `cpu0`. Furthermore, the number directly following `cpu` in these lines should be stored as an `int` into `int cpu`.

I really tried to get my head around this and I can at least get the correct lines to print by using character classes. My `if`-statement contains:

```
sscanf(line, "cpu%*1[^ ]%d", &cpu) != 1)
```

where `%1[^ ]` means read in the line until you encounter a single whitespace (the `1` is probably not needed) and then store the following number `%d` in `int cpu`. But the wrong values are stored for the `cpuN`-lines. Instead of storing `0, 1, 2, 3` the values `22942, 23879, 21510, 21824` are stored. Now this can be traced back to my usage of `%1[^ ]`. But I tried so many different things that I might be missing the obvious. How can I print all lines except the ones where `cpu` is followed (without a whitespace) by a number `N` and storing `N` in `int cpu`? (I'd like to avoid using `regex.h` if possible.) Here is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main(void)
{
    FILE * fp;
    char * line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;

    fp = fopen("/proc/stat", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
        int cpu;
         if (sscanf(line, "cpu%*1[^ ]%d", &cpu) != 1) {
            printf("%s", line);
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);
    if (line)
        free(line);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not want to suppress the assignment of the digit after `cpu`.  However, you also don't want to skip blanks, so you need to use either `%c` or `%[]` since all other formats (other than `%n`, which definitely doesn't count in this contex) skip leading blanks.  That, in turn, means you need to read a character string, not an integer. So, the code should be:

```
char cpu_str[8];  // Allow for big machines!
if (sscanf(line, "cpu%7[^ ]", cpu_str) != 1)
    printf("%s", line);
else if (sscanf(cpu_str, "%d", &cpu) != 1)
    …oops: may the scanset should be %7[0-9]…
else
    …cpu contains the cpu number…
```

Comment: Thank you. The point about having `cpu` as an `int` was to be able to use it in a `snprintf` statement later on with `%d` and some other stuff. Would there be a way to achieve this? Casting?

Comment: Take a closer look at the code I gave.  The second `sscanf()` converts the string that was read by the first into a number in `cpu`.  Of course, you could also print the string with `%s` instead of the number with `%d`, but the fragment does give you what your code tried to give you.

Comment: Oh, really sorry about that! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

suggest:

1) read line into buffer

2) strncmp (buffer, "cpu ") if 0, ignore line // notice trailing space

3) strncmp (buffer, "cpu" ) if 0, saved = atoi( buffer[3] ) // no trailing space

4) ignore all other lines